# Nokogiri Compilation Error - Can't find libraries/headers

Tags: c, ruby, rubygems, compilation

Trying to install a gem, but it can't find the headers, despite specifying them:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/lib --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/include/libxml2  --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/include/libxml2  --with-xslt-include=/usr/local/include/libxslt
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/lib --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/include/libxml2 --with-xslt-include=/usr/local/include/libxslt
checking for #include <libxml/parser.h>
... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
```

The `/usr/local/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h` file does exist, so I don't see why this isn't working.

EDIT: I'm on Centos 5.4

Comment: What happens when you install without all those options?

Comment: Same thing happens actually. I installed from source btw, and I did do `sudo make install` at the end, confirmed by existence of the compiled binaries in the appropriate directories.

Answer (score 1):

If you dig into `/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/mkmf.rb` you can figure out how to simulate the check that's happening during install. In my case I could do this by creating a file called `conftest.c` containing:

```
#include <libxml/parser.h>
```

Then try running the command that gets passed into the `try_do` function. In my case this was:

```
gcc -E -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -I-I-I/opt/local/include -I-I-I/usr/local/include -I-I-I/usr/include -I-I-I/usr/include -I-I-I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I-I/opt/local/include -I-I/usr/local/include -I-I/usr/include -I-I/usr/include -I-I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2   -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -g -DXP_UNIX -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline  conftest.c -o conftest.i
```

In my case I was missing `gcc`, which is probably not what you're hitting since you said you compiled from source. But hopefully if you run this command it should give you an idea of why you can't load in libxml2.

If you're interested in pre-built apparently [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) has a [rubygems-nokogiri](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/repoview/rubygem-nokogiri.html) package. Good chance I'll go this route in the end.