# Error Installing Rails 4.2 on Redhat 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to install rails 4.2 on redhat 6.6.  I have installed ruby 2.0.0 using rvm without an issue; however, when I try to issue:

```
gem install ruby
```

I get the following error:

```
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.2... ERROR, review '/home/smcgarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/compile.log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

When I check compile.log, I see the following:

```
./.libs/libxml2.a(xmlIO.o): In function `xmlGzfileOpen_real':
xmlIO.c:(.text+0x10d3): undefined reference to `gzopen64'
./.libs/libxml2.a(xmlIO.o): In function `xmlGzfileOpenW':
xmlIO.c:(.text+0x126e): undefined reference to `gzopen64'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [xmllint] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/smcgarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/libxml2-2.9.2'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/smcgarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/libxml2-2.9.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm not very knowledgable when it comes to Linux admin stuff so I'm not really sure what to do from here. It sounds as though I might have an outdate version of zlib (installed version is zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64).  However, I haven't been able to find a way to upgrade this.  Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where go to next?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby-debug Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697359/ruby-debug-could-not-create-makefile-due-to-some-reason-probably-lack-of-necess)