# gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to create a website using the same. I have added a few gems to my gem file and trying to bundle them, but encounter this error.

> An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
> Make sure that gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' succeeds before bundling.

I have tried doing `gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7'` but get this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 
 current directory: /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
 make "DESTDIR=" clean
 current directory: /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
 make "DESTDIR=" compiling binder.cpp In file included from

binder.cpp:20: ./project.h:119:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
 #include <openssl/ssl.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. make: *** [binder.o] Error 1
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: It would be helpful for you to state more context. Which O.S., which version of rails? Myself, when encoutering bundle install issues, I follow the steps outlined in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336160/how-to-install-nokogiri-ruby-gem-with-mkmf-log-saying-libiconv-not-found/12336375#12336375

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <openssl/ssl.h>
```

You seem to be missing the c++ development source necessary for ruby to install openssl.

Install `libssl-dev` and try the gem installation again.  You may be missing other development libraries as well.

Comment: I tried to do that but still gives me the same error.