# libxml2 is missing for Nokogiri after xcode install on mavericks osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, nokogiri, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install the nokogiri gem on mavericks and getting the error:

```
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
```

Libxml2 is installed via homebrew. I've installed xcode as suggested on other stackoverflow questions, but the issue still remains.

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134423/os-x-lion-attempting-nokogiri-install-libxml2-is-missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134423/os-x-lion-attempting-nokogiri-install-libxml2-is-missing)

Comment: I am having the same issue.  After working for 8 hours, I wiped my Mac clean and started over and got the same result.  What did you do to resolve this?

Comment: I moved on, however it looks like this guy resolved something similar https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1091

Answer (score 2):

I had to be explicit about it's location, as well as for iconv. It was a few weeks ago but I seem to remember it being like this:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-lib=[path on your system] --with-xml2-include=[path on your system] --with-iconv-dir=[path on your system]
```

These for me (OSX 10.9) are:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-lib=/opt/local/lib --with-xml2-include=/opt/local/include/libxml2 --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local
```

Comment: In order to get this to work for me (10.10) I also needed to include the use-system- libraries option `gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/opt/local/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/opt/local/lib --with-xslt-dir=/opt/local`

Comment: That worked for me though on my system (OpenSUSE) the option is ```--with-xml2lib``` (not hyphenated).  I've had Nokogiri/libxml problems on all my Mac and Linux systems.